# XAMPP is not starting Apache on XP

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I setup a new XP machine with no software except drivers and VNC.

I downloaded **XAMPP 1.8** from their website.

Apache won't start. I looked in the `EventViewer` for details and saw

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 456 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax e
rror on line 17 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load /xam
pp/php/php5ts.dll into server: The application has failed to start because its s
ide-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for
more detail.
```

I've been searching the web high and low and can't figure this out.

Comment: What is there in line 456 in httpd.conf and what is there in line 17 in httpd-xampp.conf

Comment: Go to `C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and insert in here some of the text near line 456. Also insert some text near line 17 from `C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discovered that I needed to install the VC++ redistributable software. XAMPP should make that more noticable so people who have not installed it dont panic!

Comment: would you add more information what you exactly did, because I have the same problem, please :)

Comment: I uninstalled XAMPP (completely). Make sure the folder is gone. Sometimes it's there and you need to remove it. Then I installed VC++ redistributable software. Then reboot. Then Install XAMPP from Installer.

Comment: Thank you, I've downloaded it from http://tinyurl.com/885nral and tomorrow I'll give a try, because I'm trying to run XAMPP on USB stick on PC I don't own and I'm not sure I have permissions to install stuff.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the tips. I'm finally able to run XAMPP's Apache in **Windows Server 2003**. I remember that this VC++ Redistributable is a requirement to run PHP5 on Windows. I totally forgot about it because the redistributable software is always available on all of the machine I've used previously. Good thing I found this post. :)